# Featured posts in FAQ redirect wrongly

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, featured-questions

The featured posts which are shown under the frequently asked questions on Meta Stack Overflow are wrongly linked [to a different post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22/311398)

[image]

I'm quite sure that it was not the case earlier.

Comment: Happens for me as well, but only for the first two listed questions.

Comment: Yep, they're the featured ones. Something messed up when they moved back to old-nav.

Comment: That `22` you're seeing in the URL is the ID of the [featured] tag.

Comment: Happening on Meta SE now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306345/270345

Comment: @muru, yeah, it's been broken on both sites since long, but not many have used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that; during a bit of cleanup aimed at improving site startup time a few weeks back a small error crept into the query responsible for generating those links... Well, it ended up tossing multiple Id columns into the results, and the wrong one got picked for the Id of the post.

This is now fixed.